# NoSuchMethodError coming while setting values to Cell using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i am getting below error at `cell.setCellValue("sdjcb")`;
can any one please help

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STXstring org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTRst.xgetT()'
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString.<init>(XSSFRichTextString.java:92)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellType(XSSFCell.java:928)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellTypeImpl(XSSFCell.java:903)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellBase.setCellType(CellBase.java:57)
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhz75.png]

Comment: What is your version of Apache POI and Java in your project?

Comment: Looks like you have mis-matched Apache POI jars on your classpath. How are you adding your dependencies? How are you deploying them? What else is already on your classpath?

Comment: @arch2be java 15 and apache POI 5 versions

Comment: @Gagravarr please find the update question for list of versions  i am using all latest versions

Comment: Don't mix jars between Apache POI versions! Remove the `4.1.2` jar

Comment: @Gagravarr i removed it but still same error throwing

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html There is a information for Version of ooxml-schemas. If you use POI 5.0.0 and newer you should use poi-ooxml-full jar. 
But remove ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar

Comment: @arch2be  should i remove poi-ooxml too?

Comment: Try remove only poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar and ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar

Comment: adding poi-ooxm-full and removing ooxml-schemas worked thanks @arch2be

Answer (score 1):

Here is a information about correct version of poi-schemas and version of poi: [link](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html).
Delete `poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar` and `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` and add `poi-ooxm-full`.